# Implementing OAuth 2.0 authentication with a Laravel API

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, laravel, oauth

I'm currently building a web application which is an AngularJS frontend that communicates with a RESTful API built using Laravel. I'm making good progress, but finding it hard to get my head around how to handle user authentication.

I've been advised that I should be using OAuth for authentication, and I've decided to use it seen as it could be a learning experience for me as well. The package I'm using to handle this is [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel).

The basic user story is that users can register their username/password combination for the application, and they then log into the application with that same username and password. They're only authenticated by their username and password, and not by any client secret. After login, they should be given an access token which will be send along with every future request to authenticate them on different API endpoints.

The OAuth2 library has a "password flow" grant type which seems to be what I need, however it also takes `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters, which I don't want. The request URI is something like this:

```
POST https://www.example.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=password&
client_id=the_client_id&
client_secret=the_client_secret&
username=the_username&
password=the_password&
scope=scope1,scope2&
state=123456789
```

But what I want is just:

```
POST https://www.example.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=password&
username=the_username&
password=the_password
```

How am I meant to provide a client ID and secret of a user that has yet to authenticate?

Is there a different grant I can be using, or is what I want to achieve just not suited for OAuth at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take into account, that `client id` and `client secret` aren't parameters that you have to force your end-user to pass. They are static and defined in/for your client app (angular app in this case).

All you need to do is to create a record for your main app in `oauth_clients` table, and create a scope with full access in `oauth_scopes` table, and send this values when requesting token.

And that's all in fact.

Also, you may want to consider using implicit grant flow in case of building js-only application, because storing client secret and refresh token in a js app is insecure. Using implicit grant in a final product may look like login window on soundcloud and is more secure as the token is obtained server-side without exposing client secret.

Another way to go, if you still want to use password flow is creating a proxy for refreshing tokens. Proxy can hide your refresh token in encrypted http-only cookie, and your js-app don't ask your api for new token, but the proxy instead. Proxy reads refresh token from encrypted cookie, asks the api for new token and returns it. So the refresh token is never exposed. If you set token ttl for an hour let's say, then stealing a token would be quite "pointless*" in case of a normal application, and stealing refresh token would be "impossible*".

*Of course if someone really want he probably could hack it any way.

And yeah, i know this all looks a bit hacky - modal windows for logging in, proxy etc. But also searching on this topic i couldn't find any better and more elegant way of doing it. I think that's still a lack that all js-apps have to deal with if you want a token based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something with the OAuth specification. The `client_id` and `client_secret` are really important when asking for an access token when using the password method of OAuth v2. In fact, they are important for every method that gives you an access token. They identify the application or the server that has perform the request.

For example, let's say you have your API, 2 mobile applications and another server that do some tasks with your API. You will create 3 clients with their own `client_id` and `client_secret`. If your application has various access levels (they are called `scopes` in OAuth v2), the `client_id` corresponding to the other server will be able to call functions of your API that require the scope `admin` whereas your mobile application will only be able to call functions of your API that require the `basic` scope if you have defined scopes like this.

If your API grows up in the future, this is really essential. Another example, let's imagine you have given an API key (a pair `client_id` and `client_secret`) to one of your friend and he has build a nice mobile app with your API. If one day he starts doing naughty things with your API, you can't stop him very easily. Whereas you could have just removed his key pair if you had followed  OAuth v2 principles.

OAuth v2 is not an easy thing to understand, take the time to read specifications and good tutorials before developing your API.

Some useful links :

- The official RFC : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
- A tutorial on Tutsplus : http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/oauth-20-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly--net-33216

Answer (score -1):

Just to add a bit to plunntic's excellent answer: remember "client" is not related to "user", so when I use a password flow I just define the client_id and client_secret as constants on the AngularJS app to tell the api backend: hey, this is the browser app that is being used to request a token.

Comment: The link is now 404ing.

Comment: Thanks jezmck. I have updated the link. The post is pretty old by now and there has been major developments like Passport to make this a lot easier.